# Angularjs, no puedo llamar a una función de un servicio!

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo un problema con Angularjs, estoy intentando llamar a un servicio, desde un controlador. 
La aplicación esta enlazada con el siguiente modulo:

```
var app = angular.module('sonidoambiental', ['ngRoute']).
        config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: 'inicio.html', abstract: true, controller: "InicioController"}).
                when('/listado', {templateUrl: 'listado.html', controller: "ListadoController"})./*
      when('/agregar', {templateUrl: 'plantillas/agregar.html', controller: ControladorAgregar}).*/
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    }]);
```

El servicio lo declaro de la siguiente manera

```
 app.factory('comunicacion', function() {
        return {        
        obtenerstring: function(pregunta){            
            var retorna;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/json/' + encodeURI(pregunta),
                dataType: 'json',
                method: 'get',
                success: function(datos) {
                    /* Si todo ha ido bien mostramos una alerta con el contenido */
                    if (typeof datos.error !== 'undefined' && datos.error === false) {
                        console.log(datos.mensaje);
                        retorna= datos.mensaje;                        
                        //alert("Mensaje recibido: " + datos.mensaje);
                    } else {
                        retorna = null;                        
                    }
                }
            });
            return retorna;
        }
        }        
    });
```

y lo llamo desde el controlador de la siguiente manera

```
app.controller("InicioController",['$scope', 'comunicacion',function ($scope, $interval, comunicacion) {    
    $scope.primerinicio=function(){  
        if (comunicacion.obtenerstring('sinusuarios') === ' ') {
            titulodeformulario = "No hay usuario creado por favor ingrese los datos correspondientes";                                       
                        crearusuario = true;
                        botoningresar = "Crear usuario";    
                        $scope.titulodeformulario = titulodeformulario;
                        $scope.botoningresar = botoningresar;
                        $scope.crearusuario = crearusuario;
                        $scope.$apply();
        }
```

Al ejecutarlo me dice lo siguiente

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'obtenerstring' of undefined
>       at b.$scope.primerinicio

Es obvio que esta mal declarado obtenerstring, no se como se declara correctamente para que me devuelva tal como funcion! gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fijate en la inyección de dependencias:

```
app.controller("InicioController",
['$scope', 'comunicacion',
function ($scope, $interval, comunicacion) { ... })
```

Tienes 2 nombres para inyectar, pero 3 argumentos en la función del controller.

Comment: $interval sobra? eso me quieres decir no entiendo

Comment: Si no lo ocupas, sobra. De lo contrario tambien debes declararlo en el arreglo de definicion de dependencias como `['$scope', '$interval', 'comunicacion', function...`

Comment: tu respuesta sencilla es correcta, el problema que me surge ahora es que me devuelve el item undefinited, el código fuera de esa sircunstancias funciona bien, estoy seguro que el valor retornado no es undefinited, por favor podrias decirme donde esta el error? estoy seguro %100 que retorna un valor porque he colocado console.log(respuesta) y retorna tiene un valor.

Comment: Es posible que la inyección de la factoría no se haya hecho correctamente y por eso te esté dando undefined. ¿Los has enlazado mediante el módulo? No se ve la definición de app en los ejemplos que pones.

Comment: ahi agregue en la pregunta el modulo!! muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: formulare una nueva preguna sino y tratare el tema, asi no te apabullo mas a ti muchas gracias!